# Filter four features from a vector shapefile to create a new layer to perform buffer, intersection and union on it, in QGIS 2.18?

Tags: qgis, buffer, intersection, features, union

From a dataset that contains points of interest defined by type of object with four different features, I am trying to distinguish the features to perform different analysis. Thought I had to filter the four features but that doesn't seem to be the way to go to separate them.

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. Your question is a bit indifferent, some more specification would be useful so we could help you out easier. Currently it is not evident whether you are asking how to perform `filter by`, how to run operations on filtered features, or something else.

Comment: The first thing to do I think is to separate your features. After you have done your filtering, you can right click on the layer in the legend and click "save as". It will create a new vector layer of your single feature. Then you can use buffer, intersection, union on them separately.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly (that you want to divide a layer into individual features) then you can use

```
Vector > Data Management > Split Vector Layer
```

This will divide it into individual features that you can perform separate analyses on.

Alternatively you could select one feature at a time and when performing your analysis just check the Selected Features Only box.